# gradle keyAlias Chinese(中文)

Tags: android-studio, keystore, signature

I'm trying to use android studio and gradle to build my application. I was keeping using adt and every thing works well. For my keystore, the keyAlias is in Chinese. When I switch to android studio, I configure the keystore as below:

```
        keyAlias '中文'
        keyPassword 'my_keystore'
        storeFile file('my_keystore')
        storePassword 'my_keystore'
```

But, there is error *Failed to read key from keystore*. While I have also generated a temp keystore with English keyAlias (for test), it works well, the apk is generated.

English version:

```
        keyAlias 'my'
        keyPassword 'my_keystore'
        storeFile file('my_keystore')
        storePassword 'my_keystore'
```

So how to fix this?

BTW, I have tried to change the gradle.bat(Windows)

```
 set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

it does not work.

Comment: I also have the problem, do you solve it?